# Jhipster hazelcast seperate host configuration

Tags: jhipster, hazelcast

I would like to configure a jhipster app with hazelcast running as an independent process on a separate host. Can someone guide me with doing the same?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Could you share your reference application and I can guide you through config. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @VikGamov It's just a standard basic monolith app generated from jhipster generator.

Comment: Ok, ill take a look

Comment: I was able to solve it. Thank you !

Comment: Do you care to posting your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured to use the Hazelcast client instead of creating a local embedded hazelcast node.

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
    log.debug("Configuring Hazelcast");
    // Config config = new Config();
    // config.setInstanceName("app");
    // config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
    // config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    // config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(applicationProperties.getCache().getHost());
    // config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);

    // if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
    //     System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");

    //     //config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(true);
    //     config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
    //     //config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
    // }

    // config.getMapConfigs().put("default", initializeDefaultMapConfig());
    // config.getMapConfigs().put("com.sensei.app.domain.*", initializeDomainMapConfig(applicationProperties));
    // config.getMapConfigs().put("my-sessions", initializeClusteredSession(applicationProperties));

    // hazelcastInstance = HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.addAddress(applicationProperties.getCache().getHost());
    hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    return hazelcastInstance;
}
```

Sorry for my delayed response.